What is the basis for inserting words not in the original into the translation of Zhuangzi?
A rather confusing line from Zhuangzi chapter 2 reads:

以指喻指之非指，不若非指喻指之非指。以马喻马之非马，不若非马喻马之非马。

In the Library of Chinese Classics Chinese-English edition, this is translated by Wang Rongpei as

Using a thumb to show that it is not a finger is not as good as using something else to show that it is not a finger. Using a white horse to show that it is not a horse is not as good as using something else to show that it is not a horse.

However, this translation is inserting words not in the original. (The introduction of the translation says that the translators at times decided to resort to non-literal, interpreted translations to aid Western readers on tricky passages). With my limited understanding of Classical Chinese, I would translate this as

To use a finger to prove a finger is not a finger is not as good as using a non-finger to show that a finger isn't a finger. To use a horse to prove a horse is not a horse is not as good as using a non-horse to show that a horse isn't a horse.

I know enough Classical Chinese to see that there is no hint of "thumb" or "white horse" in the original language. Interestingly, this isn't just something the translators added for the aid of Westerners, since their translation to modern Chinese also adds "thumb" and "white horse".
Where does this interpretation come from? Is it a reference to something else that I am unaware of? Perhaps some older commentary on Zhuangzi?

This is called textual emendation, altering corrupt and/or obscure text to flesh out its meaning. Especially common for ancient texts that came down to us after multiple copying by less than competent scribes, and with original meanings of words lost or shifted. "To use a finger to prove a finger is not a finger is not as good as using a non-finger to show that a finger is not a finger" is too much of a patter to convey the message. Of course, emendation always runs a risk of misinterpreting the intended meaning.

@Conifold I think Zhuangzi is writing of high enough caliber that I suspect that level of patter is intentional and part of the point. I doubt that someone could accidentally write 指 (finger) 6 times in 16 characters unironically. Especially since the next sentence is exactly the same, with 指 swapped for 马 (horse)

@DarkMalthorp "Especially since the next sentence is exactly the same, with 指 swapped for 马 (horse)" Apparently, one scribe didn't copy right. The first part of the second sentence, namely, 以马喻马之非指, should read 以马喻马之非马.

@Speakpigeon oh that scribe was me lol

@DarkMalthorp Yeah, thought so. I wonder if typos are not somewhat less likely in Chinese. Do we know if scribes often committed mistakes in copying documents?


以指喻指之非指，不若非指喻指之非指。以马喻马之非马，不若非马喻马之非马。

Wang Rongpei's translation may be rather crummy, and you're right that there is no mention of a thumb here (or even of any fingers really) or of a "white horse". The word 指 zhǐ in ordinary contexts indeed means "finger", but it can also mean "pointer", "marker" or be used as verb "to point", "the pointing".
The line in Zhuangzi is pretty difficult to understand, and there is no unanimous interpretation of what Zhuangzi intended to say, but it is clear (accepted by all sinologists and easy to verify for yourself) that Zhuangzi is referring to (quoting and partially misquoting) two paradoxical, extremely interesting statements in two short treatises attributed to the 'sophist' (or 'logician') Gongun Long:

物莫非指，而指非指。
There is no THING that is not a POINTER, but a POINTER/POINTING is not a POINTER. (Gongsun Longzi: 指物論/Discourse on things and pointers)


白馬非馬
A white horse is not a horse. (Gonsun Longzi: 白馬論/White horse discourse

So, the emandation of "Using a white horse" corrects the quote.
Zhuangzi, in the second chapter of his book, the Discourse on Equalizing Things, tries to think through and critize certain theories of meaning and knowledge that were proposed by the Mohists and other theories or paradoxes  expressed by the so-called sophists, people like his good friend Hui Shi and Gongsun Long (later, during the Han dynasty classified as belonging to the so-called 名家 míng-jiā, the School of Names).
For anyone who has studied modern logic, it's impossible not to be reminded of Frege's paradox: "The concept horse is not a concept". Gongsun Long was trying to elucidate the relation between objects and referring symbols (pointers). Exactly how to interpret his treatise is unclear; there are several interpretations, both by Chinese thinkers (Hu Shi, Feng Youlan, others) and current Western sinologists. -- One of the immense tragedies in intellectual world history is that with the fall of the Qin and the rise of the Han, the School of Names died out, and with it the attempt to reach a deeper theoretical understanding of semantics and logic. Confucianism became the dominant philosophical tradition; their doctrine of "rectiying names" did not include interest in purely theoretical paradoxes. Even in the last, syncretist Tianxia chapter of the Zhuangzi, we can see that the sophists were considered to be able debaters but criticized for not giving actual moral or political guidance. For instance in Tianxia/Gongsun Long the moralistic conclusion is:

They vanquished men in argument, but couldn't win over their hearts.


Thanks! I thought there must have been some context I was lacking. I missed the overloading on the character 指 as well, but in hindsight that is obviously relevant too.
